# Python, Do I need to return an object that was passed in as parameter?

Tags: python, pep8, pep

When writing a function which accepts a mutable object, which will could be changed, is it necessary to return this object to the caller?

By necessary I mean...

1. Is there a specific PEP guideline around this?
2. If not, what is most common in the world of Python programming?

A little bit of code:

```
def foo(args):
    args['a'] = 'new-value'
    args['b'] = args['b'] + 1

    # is there a need for a 'return args' ?

args = {'a': 'old-value', 'b': 99}
foo(args) # is there a need for args = foo(args)
print(args['a'], args['b']) # outputs new-value 100
```

"Explicit is better than implicit." makes me think I should make the potential for `args` to change very explicit in the main body, so that one does not have to look into the function to see if `args` might be changed...

Comment: I think it better to have return so i can do `print(foo(args))` immediately

Comment: Usually, methods that modify the object return `None` unless it makes sense to return something else (eg, `popitem`). I don't have any pointer right now though.

Comment: Back with a relevant mail from one of python developers. Not a PEP, but interesting read anyway: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html

Comment: Not a style issue, I would say this wouldn't fall under PEP8

Answer (score 2):

This is not covered by any PEP, and it's really up to style of the author. Generally in API design though, methods that mutate arguments won't return anything so you don't forget you're mutating things. Be very careful with this kind of design.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of what is more commonplace in python, there are some examples where the object passed is altered.  These tend to be methods of the object to be amended (e.g. `list.append`, where list is a type), but most functions tend to take a copy of the object passed and return a new one (e.g. string.strip, where string is the module `string`).

This of course also brings up `str.strip` which is also a method of a `str` type object which returns a new object.